# Проблема с загрузкой на WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

В главном `Activity` есть `WebView`, я хочу туда прямой загрузить файл. И указал там так:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
```

Но когда запускаю программу, оно просто закроется и откроется блокнот, с ошибкой что не найден файл.
Как можно это победить?

Comment: Файл точно в папке ассетов лежит?

Comment: Да. Я же не буду указать несуществующий путь

Comment: а вместо file по моему assets надо писать

Comment: Путь указан верно. Если я использую `ListView` и в нем укажу путь для загрузки этого файла в `WebView`, то оно без проблем загрузиться. Но таким способом прямо не получается загрузить.